# Are pallet:constants really constant?

Tags: frame-system, constants

The docs say that the benefit of this macro is that the "value is included in the metadata", but from what I can gather, there is nothing which pins down this value at compile time? That is, someone can provide a `Get` implementation which is based on storage state, block number or any other non-constant input.

1. Am I mistaken?
2. What value would actually be put in metadata?
3. Does a mutable `pallet::constant` cause problems for the node or Polkadotjs or some other part of the stack?

**Edit:**

Seems that `frame_support::parameter_types` can indeed be backed by a mutable storage item, but not sure what that implies for 2 and 3 above.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, Rust does not have stable support for [const generics](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9865) or [const traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792), and similar stuff.

Your Pallet constants SHOULD be constant, and it is your job as a runtime developer to ensure you implement them properly.

But yes, it is unfortunately currently possible to implement such items as non-const, and it will make your metadata act funny (like change block to block).

Comment: 1) Thanks for clarifying.
2) Changing metadata would actually be fine, I am worried it breaks something else, and you are saying that inside the node or otherwise you can't think of any serious problem?

Comment: But actually, why does `frame_support::parameter_types` support mutable parameters if I _should_ keep everything constant?

Comment: All pallet constants are MEANT to be constant. You should not make them non-constant. The fact that you can is just a Rust thing. Dont do it.